# Replacing IF statement (random condition) with boolean logic- execution time identical?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, branch, cpu

(Setup: Win 7 64, MSVC, 3rd Generation Core i7, 64-bit compliation, -O2 enabled)

The below code has three functions- one has an IF statement which executes different code depending on whether a condition has been met. I replaced this IF statement with some boolean logic. However the timings are identical.... I was expecting the lack of branch prediction to yield faster code:

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long iterations = 1000000000;

void test1(){
    volatile int c = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<iterations; i++){
        bool condition = __rdtsc() % 2 == 0;
        if(condition){
            c = 4;
        }
        else{
            c = 5;
        }
    }
}

void test2(){
    volatile int c = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<iterations; i++){
        bool condition = __rdtsc() % 2 == 0;
        c = (4 * condition) + (5 * !condition);
    }
}

int main(){
    unsigned long long s = 0;
    unsigned long long f = 0;
    unsigned long long s2 = 0;
    unsigned long long f2 = 0;
    unsigned int x = 0;
    unsigned int y = 0;

    start = __rdtscp(&x);
    test1();
    finish = __rdtscp(&y);

    start2 = __rdtscp(&x);
    test2();
    finish2 = __rdtscp(&y);

    std::cout << "1: " << f - s<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "2: " << f2- s2<< std::endl;
}
```

UPDATE asm:

```
int main(){
 push        rbp  
 push        rsi  
 push        rdi  
 push        r14  
 sub         rsp,20h  
    unsigned long long start = 0;
    unsigned long long finish = 0;
    unsigned long long start2 = 0;
    unsigned long long finish2 = 0;
    unsigned long long start3 = 0;
    unsigned long long finish3 = 0;
    unsigned int x = 0;
 xor         r8d,r8d  
 mov         dword ptr [x],r8d  
    unsigned int y = 0;
 mov         dword ptr [y],r8d  

    start = __rdtscp(&x);
 rdtscp  
 lea         r9,[x]  
 shl         rdx,20h  
 mov         dword ptr [r9],ecx  
 or          rax,rdx  
    test1();
 mov         dword ptr [rsp+60h],r8d  
 mov         ecx,r8d  

    start = __rdtscp(&x);
 mov         r10,rax  
 nop         word ptr [rax+rax]  
    test1();
 rdtsc  
 shl         rdx,20h  
 or          rax,rdx  
 xor         al,0FFh  
 and         al,1  
 neg         al  
 sbb         eax,eax  
 inc         ecx  
 add         eax,5  
 mov         dword ptr [rsp+60h],eax  
 movsxd      rax,ecx  
 cmp         rax,3E8h  
    test1();
 jb          main+40h (013FFE1280h)  
    finish = __rdtscp(&y);
 rdtscp  
 lea         r9,[y]  
 shl         rdx,20h  
 or          rax,rdx  
 mov         dword ptr [r9],ecx  
 mov         rbp,rax  

    start2 = __rdtscp(&x);
 rdtscp  
 lea         r9,[x]  
 shl         rdx,20h  
 mov         dword ptr [r9],ecx  
 or          rax,rdx  
    test2();
 mov         dword ptr [rsp+60h],r8d  
 mov         r9d,r8d  

    start2 = __rdtscp(&x);
 mov         r14,rax  
 nop         word ptr [rax+rax]  
    test2();
 rdtsc  
 shl         rdx,20h  
 inc         r9d  
 or          rax,rdx  
 xor         al,0FFh  
 and         al,1  
    test2();
 movzx       ecx,al  
 lea         eax,[rcx+rcx*8]  
 mov         dword ptr [rsp+60h],eax  
 movsxd      rax,r9d  
 cmp         rax,3E8h  
 jb          main+0A0h (013FFE12E0h)  
    finish2 = __rdtscp(&y);
```

Comment: did you compile with optimizations?

Comment: Do they generate different code? Compilers know some of the tricks for removing branches like that.

Comment: (You might get better answers if you modified s, f, s2 or f2 somewhere in the code. And ran more iterations.)

Comment: @AlanStokes I get same results for 1 billion iterations.

Comment: @inixsoftware -O2 turned on

Comment: You probably mean `5 * !condition` btw - as it stands the two loops aren't equivalent.

Comment: The time for these loops are limited by the call to rdtsc, and therefore the time is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The generated code doesn't contain any internal branches for either function, which is why there is no mis-prediction penalty.

In the first one it converts the boolean to either zero or -1 (around `sbb eax,eax`) and adds it to 5. This is a pretty standard optimisation when working with booleans.

In the second one it multiplies by nine (`rcx+rcx*8`), because you have `5 * condition` not `5 * !condition`.

Comment: Thanks for that- knocked up the example so quickly I didnt notice.

Comment: The overhead of reading the counter might also diminish the difference between the two codes. It is somewhat surprising that the compiler did not just use `c=4+(__rdtsc() &0x1)`. On the other hand, a clever compiler would recognize the absence of side effects (no use of `c`) and just elide the loop.

Comment: @Paul Writing to a `volatile` is defined to be a side effect.

Comment: @AlanStokes Sorry, I did not notice the volatile declaration.